# Edittext's text overlapped by softkeyboard's scroll bar

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a simple app that consists of a multiline edittext, when I try to enter some large text in the landscape mode the and press enter so that the scroll bar appears.The scroll bar overlaps the text I've entered.

How to shift the scrollbar or limit the no. of characters entered in a line so that the scroll bar doesn't overlap with the text??

[image: Edittext in Landscape editting mode]

Comment: I've tried posting an image, but that need minimum 10 reputations, which I don't have :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` 
inside the `EditText` in your xml will do the trick.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Its the framework issue.Hence the edittex of=r the softkeyboard cannot handle this issue.